# Is it possible to use Flutter in Apple's Application Extensions?

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-app-extension

I am looking for a way to implement a [Share Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1) for iOS / macOS using Flutter. I'd like to use Flutter Widgets and Flutter Plugins in that extension. My idea was to have the extension's `UIViewController` present a `FlutterViewController` as described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=vc-swift-tab#show-a-flutterviewcontroller-with-your-flutterengine). But when I try to link against the Flutter library, I am getting the "linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application extensions" warning. I suppose this is because the Flutter library isn't an extension-safe API as per the guidelines.

So my question is, has anybody here successfully used Flutter in their App Extension? I am not looking for a hack, but for an official way that will pass Apple's app review guidelines.

Comment: Did you manage to implement the share extension in Flutter after all?

Comment: No. Due to the above mentioned doubts regarding Apple guidelines, I decided to implement the share part for each platform in the platform-specific language. Not great but I wanted to be safe.